# How to check whether list is sorted or not in Robotframework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to run below code but getting below error as -:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'WebElement' and 'WebElement'

```
${original_list} =    Get WebElements     ${accountsid}
${sorted_list}= SORT LIST    ${original_list}
click element      ${sort_button}
${after_sorting}=     Get WebElements     ${slot_Sorting_Slot_Id}
lists should be equal    ${sorted_list}    ${after_sorting}
```

Comment: web element is not int or decimal that can be sorted. Why you want to sort your web elements list?

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message says, you cannot compare objects of type WebElements. This is because they are a block of data with an ID, that webdriver provided to the user. This data allows to reference the real HTML element on the browser.

In your test script, you need additional steps to get the real data you need to compare. Here is my proposal:

```
${original_list} =    Get Data    ${accountsid}
${sorted_list}= SORT LIST    ${original_list}
click element      ${sort_button}
${after_sorting}=     Get Data     ${slot_Sorting_Slot_Id}
lists should be equal    ${sorted_list}    ${after_sorting}
```

With `Get Data` like:

```
*** Keywords ***
Get Data
    [Arguments]    ${locator}
    Import Library    Collections    # Probably already declared globally
    @{data}=    Create List
    @{my_list}=    Get WebElements     ${locator}
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{my_list}
        ${item}=    Get Text    ${element}
        Append To List    ${data}    ${item}
    END
    Return From Keyword    ${data}
```

Comment: Thanks for help! But after running above code m getting error as -:   TypeError: Expected argument 1 to be a list or list-like, got None instead.  Somehow Sort List is not working.

Comment: Return type of Sort List is 'None' .

Comment: Well, that was not the original question, which I think I answered and should be accepted. Don't you think?

Comment: @Hope1234 "Sort List" doesn't have a return value, it sorts a list in place - If you need to keep the original list then use ${sorted_list}  Copy List  ${original_list} and then use Sort List   ${sorted_list}
As per documentation "Note that the given list is changed and nothing is returned. Use Copy List first, if you need to keep also the original order."